# How can I get an ID from json file using fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
const rptch = require('./reportch.json')

let reportchannel = message.guild.channels.find('id', `${rptch}`);
```

I used `fs.writeFile` that writes a channel ID into a `json` file, but I can't get that channel by the `json` file id

Comment: You can't write to files using `fs.readFile`. Did you mean `fs.writeFile`?

Comment: Yes! I mean fs.writeFile

Comment: great answer by you. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think in the JSON file might be:

```json
{
  "id": "ID"
}
```

In Your main file:

```js
const { id } = require('./reportch.json');
let reportChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(id);
```

#### So, what did it mean?

1. The first line you wrote down may be wrong. Because there's no **`id`** variable for the JSON file.
2. The **`reportChannel`** variable value from **`message.guild.channels.get()`** has been changed to `message.guild.channels.cache.get()` since new Discord.js v12 update.

**It completly works for me!**

##### NOTE: I used normally. No `fs` module needed

Answer (score 0):

With fs use something like this:

```js
fs = require('fs')
data = fs.readfilesync(path)
info = JSON.parse(data)
info['propertyname'] //Will give you the id.
```